# Copying pointers to objects with tables

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I have a problem when copying pointers to objects that contain tables... Some information is kept (strings, for example skillName), but the tables contain new, random data. I tried several things, but I still don't know what's wrong and how to do it... Help me, please. :)

**EDIT**: I've edited whole post, and as WhozCraig suggested made it MCVE (at least I tried). 
Everything now is in this block of code, so you can just copy it and see it for yourself. For some reason the problem is in different location now, but it's still the same...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Skill
{
protected:
    int const maxSkillLevel;
    short skillLevel;
    string skillName;

public:
    Skill(string skillName) : maxSkillLevel(5){
        skillLevel = 0;
        this->skillName = skillName;
    }

    virtual ~Skill(){}
    virtual int getMaxDmg(int i){ return 0; };

    void increaseSkillLevel(int);
    string getSkillName(){ return skillName; }
};


class OffensiveSkill : public Skill{
protected:
    int *maxDmg;

public:
    OffensiveSkill(string skillName, int maxDmg[]) : Skill(skillName){
        this->maxDmg = maxDmg;
    }

    ~OffensiveSkill(){}

    int getMaxDmg(int i){ return maxDmg[i]; }

};


class Role{
protected:
    string roleName;
    Skill **skills;

public:
    Role(string roleName){
        skills = new Skill*[3];
        this->roleName = roleName;
    }

    Role(Role* role){
        this->skills = role->getSkills();
        this->roleName = role->getRoleName();
    }

    Skill **getSkills(){ return skills; }
    string getRoleName(){ return roleName; }

    void setSkills(Skill* s1){ skills[0] = s1; }
};


class RoleGenerator{
protected:
    Role *role;
public:
    RoleGenerator(){
        role = new Role("assassin");

        int maxDmg[5] = { 30, 45, 60, 75, 90 };

        OffensiveSkill* assassinate = new OffensiveSkill("Assassinate", maxDmg);
        role->setSkills(assassinate);

        cout << "maxDmg in RoleGenerator " <<  role->getSkills()[0]->getMaxDmg(0) << endl;
    }

    Role *getRoles(){ return role; }
};


int main(){

    RoleGenerator* rg = new RoleGenerator();
    Role *role = rg->getRoles();

    cout << "maxDmg in main " << role->getSkills()[0]->getMaxDmg(0) << endl;

    Role *copied = new Role(role);

    //maxDmg here is different
    cout << "maxDmg in after copying " << role->getSkills()[0]->getMaxDmg(0) << endl;

    //but skill name is copied correctly
    cout << "skill name " <<  role->getSkills()[0]->getSkillName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1. You did not include the code that **creates** the pointer array returned from `role->getSkills()`; it is relevant. 2. That cast should be unnecessary if this is indeed the actual code. If your code doesn't compile without it, that is a sign something isn't right. Strip down the code to a simple [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Most probably the problem is that `OffensiveSkill` does not own the `maxDmg` array, and it gets overwritten in `cout.operator<<`

Comment: Too many unnecessary pointers. Getting random data is kind of a best case scenario. Use vector and unique/shared pointers (if you must) instead.

Comment: OffensiveSkill has *maxDmg (array) so there shouldn't be a problem... There are many pointers, but I need them to share data between classes. I've done as @WhozCraig said and reproduced the problem. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: @WhozCraig Edit done.

Comment: The array `int maxDmg[5] = { 30, 45, 60, 75, 90 }` is being passed as-address to `new OffensiveSkill("Assassinate", maxDmg)`, where that address is saved via `this->maxDmg = maxDmg;` After `RoleGenerator:: RoleGenerator()` returns `maxDmg` is no longer valid to address. Dereferencing that address later invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Hmm... You're right... Is there a way to get a copy of a table (instead of an address) in function? Or should I make a pointer to the table and send it?

Comment: If a copy is truly sufficient then a simple `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>` member would suffice, then copy the data at construction. If the size is always fixed at 5 elements, its simple enough. A `std::vector<>` and either an iterator-based constructor or a templates constructor would be easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **local** array in `RoleGenerator:: RoleGenerator()`

```
int maxDmg[5] = { 30, 45, 60, 75, 90 };
```

is being passed as-address to:

```
OffensiveSkill* assassinate = new OffensiveSkill("Assassinate", maxDmg);
```

where that address is saved via:

```
this->maxDmg = maxDmg;
```

After `RoleGenerator:: RoleGenerator()` returns `maxDmg` is no longer valid to address. Dereferencing the saved address later invokes undefined behavior.

If a copy is sufficient one way to make this trivial is by copying the array into a simple member array or vector. There are multiple ways to do this. A decent arbitrary-length solution using a vector would be something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class OffensiveSkill : public Skill {
protected:
    std::vector<int> maxDmg;

public:
    template<size_t N>
    OffensiveSkill(string skillName, int (&dmg)[N]) 
        : Skill(skillName)
        , maxDmg(dmg, dmg+N)
    {
    }

    int getMaxDmg(int i) const { return maxDmg[i]; }
};
```

That alone should work as a drop-in replacement for your exiting constructor and class definition. If needed you can offer up additional flexibility by providing alternate constructors, such as one that allows beginning and end iterators directly passable to `maxDmg` construction, an `int*` and `size_t` length, etc.

And I would suggest you modify your indexing member `getMaxDmg()` to (a) range check the input value and toss an exception if out of range, and (b) use an unsigned data type (such as `std::size_t`) for your indexes. Unrelated to your question, but worth considering.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working now. However... Where do I initialize N? Or is it automatically detecting size of the array I put in constructor? Function `getMaxDmg()` is just temporary, I made it to check what's wrong with my code, I don't need it otherwise, but thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: @JinLisek It is deduced from the parameter. That constructor will only work when passing a fixed length array (which happens to match what you're doing). Thus the reason I mentioned if you need someday to pass arbitrary sequences you may need to add additional constructors, but for now that one will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me so much, sir! <3

Comment: @JinLisek no worries. Thanks for posting the code needed to find the problem.

Comment: Another problem arises... How do I make a prototype of that method? And what if I wanted to have a constructor with two tables that have exactly the same size? For example maxDmg and minDmg. Would it be possible to detect N from first parameter and then pass it to other tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is looking strange:

```
skills[0] = static_cast<OffensiveSkill*>(roleSkills[0]);
```

You would need to include more of your code.

But, based on the limited information, looks like you are better off with a copy constructor that is custom. A compiler generated copy-constructor won't perform deep-copy for you.